# how to deserialise xml collection representation with restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-client

I have been on this for days on end and cant see any head way.Now the idea is to consume a url with information from a database using restful web service implemented in java.
The information is a passenger detail with reference information to baggage details implemented as a collection of bags.See below for an eg xml representation

```
  <passenger>
    <id></id>
    ....
    ....
    <boardingNo></boardingNo>
    <Bags>
    <bag>
    12345
    </bag>
    <bag>
    12345
    </bag>
    </Bags>
  </passenger>
```

I can deserialise the passenger info with a restful web service client.But when i get to the collection part i get the collection quite alright but with null references to the bag object.Need to know how to return a collection considering the XML representation seamlessly with a jersey restful web client

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following JAXB mapped class.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="passenger")
public class Passenger {

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public String id;

    @XmlElement(name="boardingNo")
    public String boardingNo;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Bags")
    @XmlElement(name="bag")
    public List<String> bags;
}
```